# FirebaseUser and User

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have problem in my app that I have to create a Database Class User , But also I have in the new FirebaseAuth there is User now instead of FirebaseUser , How can I separate them functionally ?

Answer (score 2):

Import your user model as an alias

```
import '../../User.dart' as userModel;
```

use it like

```
userModel.User user = .........
```

Answer (score 1):

Anna's solution should work. But if you're not using FirebaseAuth user in this class, you could just **hide** the User class from firebase auth like this:

```
   import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' hide User;
```

This will, as its name says, hide the class User so it won't be available in the current file.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to import `firebase_auth` package with an `as` keyword.

```dart
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebase_auth;
```

Now you can use any `firebase_auth` function or class by prepending `firebase_auth.` to the name like:

```dart
final firebaseUser = firebase_auth.User(...); 
final user = User(...);
```

I prefer this to the other way around because User class is a part of your code and you usually want to import external code `as something`.